# What's the difference between a marshaller and a serializer?

Tags: java, xml

...and unmarshalling/deserializing? [Wikipedia's explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29#Comparison_with_serialization) leaves me none-the-wiser! I'm a Java programmer, in case the terminology is used differently in different languages.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Semantics are important here:

Marshalling implies **moving** the data, it does not imply transforming the data from its native representation or storage. Java Objects can be Marshalled over the wire in their native representation.

Serializing implies **transforming** the data to some non-native intermediate representation. For example: transforming a Java Object to JSON or XML.

Of course, most systems that **Marshal** data, **Serialize** it to some non-native format before they transport it.

Answer (score 13):

This question has been asked before, but on StackOverflow. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770474/what-is-the-difference-between-serialization-and-marshalling) is the link.

Quotation of the answer given by **Jeffrey Hantin**:

> Marshaling and serialization are loosely synonymous in the context of
>   remote procedure call, but semantically different as a matter of
>   intent.
>
> In particular, marshaling is about getting parameters from here to
>   there, while serialization is about copying structured data to or from
>   a primitive form such as a byte stream. In this sense, serialization
>   is one means to perform marshaling, usually implementing pass-by-value
>   semantics.
>
> It is also possible for an object to be marshaled by reference, in
>   which case the data "on the wire" is simply location information for
>   the original object. However, such an object may still be amenable to
>   value serialization.
>
> As @Bill mentions, there may be additional metadata such as code base
>   location or even object implementation code.

Answer (score 2):

A Marshaller does whatever it needs to do, to cast a data structure to be transported from one place to another. When I talk about "Data Structure" it could be anything. From an object itself (state data => field values) to a memory reference to that object that will be handled the client side by a "Stub" and on the server side by a "Proxy".  It means that a Marshaller could use "Serializers" to transform that data structure into a low level representation much easier to transport. The transformation path could have another components like Compressors, Compilers, Adaptors etc. For me a Serializer is part of the Marshaller.